# R: Is parallel importing of functions from NAMESPACE possible?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, shiny, namespaces

I'm developing a large package that is also a Shiny app. During start of the app, there's a call to `library(myPackageName)` which results in loading all selectively imported functions from other packages. To make it clear: I don't call `library(otherPackages)` - I have a large NAMESPACE file that loads only required functions from other packages.

Since there're a lot of dependencies, the whole process takes a lot of time (north of 30s). Is there a way to speed it up via parallel execution? I know I could do it for `library` calls, but I couldn't find it for loading NAMESPACE only.

Comment: Do you really need to load everything? Maybe use `Imports` instead of `Depends` and use `package::` instead of loading all the package.

Comment: I don't think that's possible; even if you'd load the different packages in parallel, that would happen in external R processes and it would not affect the main R process (where you want it to take place). This is because parallelization in R is multi-*processed* not multi-*threaded*.

Comment: It's an interesting use case/request though; it would probably be possible to do parts of the tasks in parallel (multi-processed) by updating the internals of R to speed it up somewhat. I can also imagine it could be multi-threaded. Regardless, any such updates/improvements needs to be done at the core of R (which is beyond reach at the user level).

Comment: @F.Privé I don't load whole packages, I just selectively import functions from these packages (via @importFrom). I could use package:: calls without explicit importing in the NAMESPACE file, but I thought that's not a good practice. Might be a solution, though.

Comment: @HenrikB Thanks for the comment and for the clarification. Way too difficult for a quick hack, but maybe I will submit it as a suggestion to R core dev team.

Comment: I think using `@importFrom` or using `::` will result in the sames lines in your NAMESPACE. What is weird is that your packages are loaded explicitly when you load your package (which shouldn't be the case if you use them in ``Imports`` rather than ``Depends``).

Comment: I have my dependencies listed in `Imports`. Dependent functions are loaded but not attached (default behaviour). Attachment adds couple of seconds of overhead, but still majority of loading time is taken by `loadNamespace` function.

Comment: Okay, is your package available on GitHub?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's an internally developed piece of code (cannot share it outside of a company).